# How do you define a string in JavaScript that could contain any character?

Tags: javascript, string, passwords, salesforce, visualforce

Even though I'm using a Salesforce variable in my JavaScript, it is not necessary to know Salesforce to answer my question. There's a password field I want to access. I can do this by using the Salesforce variable, `{!Account.Password__c}`, inside my JavaScript like so:

```
var p = '{!Account.Password__c}';
```

I've been using this for a long time, but there are some instances where it doesn't work. The only problem is that the password could contain any character (as a good password should). So if it contains a single quote, then this JavaScript will not run. I could write it with double quotes:

```
var p = "{!Account.Password__c}";
```

But it could contain a double quote also. It could also contain forward slashes and/or back slashes.

The password string needs to be able to take any of these:
`Idon'tknow`
`pass"word"`
`/-\_|)_/-\_/\/\`
`"'!@#`
`+*co/rn`

This is my code:

```
var u = '{!Account.Email_Address__c}';
var p = escape(encodeURIComponent('{!Account.Password__c}'));
window.open('http://mywebsite.com/?&u=' + u + '&p=' + p,'_blank');
```

Comment: You have to handle it from the back-end if you want to feed it directly into JavaScript. *BUT WHY WHY WHY* would you be sending a password and username ina GET request. That is BAD BAD BAD. It is like taping your house key to your front door.

Comment: It will in fact require knowledge of Salesforce in order to answer the question, because it's going to have to be a Salesforce mechanism that allows strings to be scrubbed before being injected into JavaScript code.

Comment: In ASP.NET the equivalent question would be how to set `foo` such that `var p = '<%= foo %>'` works for any value of `foo`.  The answer is to do the necessary escaping to `foo` server side, prior to generating the page.  Salesforce presumably has a similar server side scrubbing mechanism.  I don't think you can do it entirely client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the JSENCODE function.  It will escape quotes, backslashes, and anything else that might mess up your Javascript string.

```
var p = '{!JSENCODE(Account.Password__c)}';
```

If your Javascript is inside an HTML tag (eg: in an 'onclick' attribute) then use the JSINHTMLENCODE function, which will html-encode the characters `<&>` .

These are documented in the [Visualforce Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that of escaping. You can backslash any character in a string - so if you have, say, `owowow"'!thisishard` as a password, to assign it straight up to a JS var, you would do this:

```
var p = "owowow\"\'!thisishard";
```

Which deals with the escaping. You do **not** need to do this if you have acquired the variable from another source (say, a text element through `element.value`).

This does not reove a couple of issues:

1. Passing passwords through GET params is pretty high up on the OWASP guidelines of things **not** to do. The reason being that they will show up on server logs in addition to being sniffable through conventional means.
2. Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: This is only for internal use for my company. The customers who actaully own the passwords do not see this or use this.
And seriously, I didn't come up with this. This is how it was when I started at the company. This is what I have to work with.

Comment: @burkybang: my comment wasn't meant to be offensive. (Side note: can we have the name of the company so I know who not to apply for? :-P the customers not using it does not change a thing. you'll still have server logs. The moment someone gets their hands on it, they have all the passwords. And it doesn't take a customer to do so - a disgruntled employee, the janitor - or someone bribing the janitor...)

Comment: Yes I agree... and we will be changing our entire system, so this problem will be addressed, but not yet.